# Pandas: setting column as index with set_index() creates a sub-index. Why is it happening and how to remove it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to use the first column in a pandas dataframe as the row index, so I am trying to do it with [pandas.set_index(0, inplace=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) but this has the side-effect of adding an extra column index.

(jupyter notebook code running with option `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"`):

```python
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[l+r*10 for l in range(1, 5)] for r in range(1, 5)])

df # before

df.set_index(0, inplace=True)

df # after
```

Dataframe before `set_index()`

[image: before set_index()]

Dataframe after `set_index()`

[image: after set_index()]

The question is why is there a second index created and how to remove it? The [set_index() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) don't mention anything about a sub-index being created.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is the zero inside the red circle is the index name.  Pandas displays the index name offset from the column headers, hence you have that space below the column headers. When using set index argument of colunn name, that column name changes into the new index name as that column is moved into the index of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @scott-boston commented, the index name is shown, which was the column name "0" in your example. If you like to remove it, you can simply use:

```
del df.index.name
```

So your full code would be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[l+r*10 for l in range(1, 5)] for r in range(1, 5)])

df # before

df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
del df.index.name

df # after
```

Comment: The del df.index.name method is no longer supported by the latest version of pandas, it raises an "AttributeError". df.index.name = None would do the trick as well.